# Not able to create Swagger API

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I am trying to create API using swagger using below changes

1) Maven dependency

```
        <dependency>    
           <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.1</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

2) Enable Swagger

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

        @Bean
        public Docket api() { 
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
              .select()                                  
              .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
              .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
              .build();                                           
        }

}
```

3) Configure resources in Spring Application Context

```
<mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/"/> 
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
```

Receiving below error while deploying in WebLogic server.

> [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "spring-servlet" failed to preload on startup
>   in Web application: "/fcesign".
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'
>   defined in URL
>   [zip:C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/onesource_domain/servers/onesource_server/tmp/_WL_user/FcESignEar/5leda2/war/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 1 of type [java.util.List]: : Error creating bean with name
>   'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined in URL
>   [zip:C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/onesource_domain/servers/onesource_server/tmp/_WL_user/FcESignEar/5leda2/war/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type [java.util.List]: : No qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]
>   found for dependency [collection of
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]
>   found for dependency [collection of
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined
>   in URL
>   [zip:C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/onesource_domain/servers/onesource_server/tmp/_WL_user/FcESignEar/5leda2/war/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type [java.util.List]: : No qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]
>   found for dependency [collection of
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]
>   found for dependency [collection of
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations: {} at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:835)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>   at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241) at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
>   at
>   weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>   at
>   weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:531)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1915)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1889)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1807)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3045)
>   at
>   weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1397)
>   at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:460)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:1267)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:409)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:54)
>   at
>   weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:181)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:12)
>   at
>   weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:67)
>   at
>   weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516)
>   at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201) at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined
>   in URL
>   [zip:C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/onesource_domain/servers/onesource_server/tmp/_WL_user/FcESignEar/5leda2/war/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type [java.util.List]: : No qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]
>   found for dependency [collection of
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]
>   found for dependency [collection of
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations: {} at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1068)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
>   ... 61 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]
>   found for dependency [collection of
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations: {} at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1071)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
>   ... 75 more Message icon - Error Substituted for missing class
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException -
>   Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined
>   in URL
>   [zip:C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/onesource_domain/servers/onesource_server/tmp/_WL_user/FcESignEar/5leda2/war/WEB-INF/lib/springfox-spring-web-2.7.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type [java.util.List]: : No qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]
>   found for dependency [collection of
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]
>   found for dependency [collection of
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping]:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for
>   this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: @Dilip Krishnan Can you help me on this.

Comment: Could you provide more details on how this is configured, is it a boot app, have u tried with 2.7.0? Also it should have more of a stacktrace, which might give clues.

Comment: @Dilip Krishnan Its Spring Rest Application not sprint boot. Not working with 2.7.0. Error coming 'Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' '

Comment: Try removing the `@Configuration` annotation from your SwaggerConfiguration` class. I'm assuming you have an `@EnableWebMvc` defined somewhere else.

Comment: @DilipKrishnan No error is coming while deploying on server but no any API report is coming on /swagger-ui.html and 404 status code for /v2/api-docs

Comment: Looks to me that you have multiple mvc contexts being loaded. You likely have a web.xml that has a context loader in play or an equivalent of enable web mvc. Since you have xml configuration why not have the swagger configuration beam also loaded in the same scope via xml configuration.